# RevTex4-1 warning: "Repair the float package"

Tags: revtex

I am compiling a simple document in pdflatex using RevTex4-1 class and am getting this warning:

```
Class revtex4-1 Warning: Repair the float package.
```

The document seems to be fine (I have a single figure in it). I can't find anything online explaining this warning though, so I decided to ask the community.  What is this?  Do I need to fix it?  If so, how?

Here is my preamble:

```
documentclass[twocolumn,noshowpacs,noshowkeys,pra,aps,longbibliography]       {revtex4-1}%
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The warning should be `Repairing the float package`, as it tells you that some action has been taken by the class. It's annoying, but innocuous. There are several other `Repairing...` warnings defined in the class and this is the only one with `Repair`, but the surrounding code is very similar to the other codes with `Repairing`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I can definitely expand my example, but looks like egreg figured it out based on my pre-amble (and wrote a very nice expensive answer below). Is MWE still needed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `revtex4-1` class defines several similar messages, for instance

```
351 \@ifx{\eqnarray\eqnarray@LaTeX}{%
352  \class@info{Repairing broken LaTeX eqnarray}%
353  \let\eqnarray\eqnarray@fleqn@fixed
354  \newlength\eqncolsep
355  \setlength\eqncolsep\z@
356  \let\eqnarray@LaTeX\relax
357  \let\eqnarray@fleqn@fixed\relax
358 }{}%
```

The warning you get is quite similar in essence:

```
3979 \appdef\document@inithook{%
3980  \@ifxundefined\newfloat{}{%
3981   \@ifx{\float@end\float@end@float}{%
3982    \@ifx{\newfloat\newfloat@float}{\true@sw}{\false@sw}%
3983    }{\false@sw}%
3984    {%
3985     \class@warn{Repair the float package}%
3986     \let\float@end\float@end@ltx
3987     \let\newfloat\newfloat@ltx
3988    }{%
3989     \class@warn{Failed to patch the float package}%
3990    }%
3991  }%
3992 }%
```

but, for some reasons, “Repairing” turned into “Repair”. It's almost certainly a small bug, but the warning is completely innocuous.

It is issued because `algorithm` loads `float`. If you want to turn it off, use the `silence` package: add

```
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{revtex4-1}{Repair the float}
```

to your preamble and the warning will disappear.

Comment: Thank you for an extensive explanation. I've seen "Repairing [something]" before and knew that there was trouble when "Failed to [do something]" appeared after that. I never saw "Repair [something]" before and thought that LaTeX was asking me to repair something manually, hence my question.  Appreciate the clarification!